# Calculate the total number of orders by new users in last 29 days using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

A csv file contain "user_ids" and "order_dates". A user may have more than 1 order date, but not on the same day. Determine the total number of orders placed by new users within their first 29 days of using the product. The user's earliest order entry = day 1.

ex: a user makes their first purchase on 2018-01-01; any additional orders placed up to and including 2018-01-29 are counted. Any order history afterward is not to be considered.

I have used SQL fiddle and have made progress in getting a count of orders returned to me. However, results returned are limited within the 29 days required.

Having a between clause should constrict the query to report sales within each user's first 29 days, but it does not.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
  (
   user_id int,
   order_date Date
  );

    INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,order_date) VALUES (5963,'2018-01-01');
    INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,order_date) VALUES (5963,'2018-01-29');
    INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,order_date) VALUES (5963,'2018-01-30');
    INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,order_date) VALUES (5962,'2018-01-01');
    INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,order_date) VALUES (5962,'2018-02-25');
    INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,order_date) VALUES (5962,'2018-04-03');
```

```
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  COUNT(order_date) AS total_orders

FROM 
  mytable 

GROUP BY 1

having 
  ROUND(julianday(order_date) - julianday(MIN(order_date))) <= 29 

order by 1 desc;
```

In the above code:

- user_id = 5963: returns 3 total orders, expected 2.
- user_id = 5962: returns 3 total orders, expected 1

Comment: How do you define a `new` user?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
mytable.user_id, 
  COUNT (mytable.order_date) AS total_orders

FROM 
  mytable 

INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, MIN(order_date) AS order_date FROM mytable GROUP BY user_id) AS earliest
ON mytable.user_id = earliest.user_id

WHERE ROUND(julianday(mytable.order_date) - julianday(earliest.order_date)) < 29 

GROUP BY mytable.user_id

ORDER BY COUNT(mytable.order_date) desc;
```

Comment: Good catch.  Syntax error is in original query and was copied over for edits.  I have corrected my answer syntax.

Comment: I obviously struggle to count parentheses in the morning before coffee. Subsequent edit should be more to your liking. :)

Comment: Yeah, that looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The following requires Sqlite 3.25 or newer because it uses a window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT user_id, order_date
      , date(first_value(order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY order_date)
           , '+29 days') AS cutoff_date
 FROM mytable)
SELECT user_id, count(order_date) AS total_orders
FROM cte
WHERE order_date < cutoff_date
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;
```

On your sample data it gives:

```
user_id     total_orders
----------  ------------
5962        1           
5963        2
```

If run frequently, consider adding an index:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_idx_uid_order ON mytable(user_id, order_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
select user_id, min(order_date) mindate
from mytable 
group by user_id
```

you can get the 1st order date for each user.
All you have to do is join it to the table:

```
select 
  m.user_id,
  count(*) total
from mytable m inner join (
  select user_id, min(order_date) mindate
  from mytable 
  group by user_id
) g on g.user_id = m.user_id
where round(julianday(m.order_date) - julianday(g.mindate)) < 29 
group by m.user_id
```

Notice that I changed the condition from `<= 29` to `< 29`, 
because what you really want is the maximum distance between the dates 
to be 28 days, like `2018-01-01` to `2018-01-29` which is `29 - 1 = 28`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cCPtrde4FZM6Tk8ZBxTPFM/0).
Results:

```
| user_id | total |
| ------- | ----- |
| 5962    | 1     |
| 5963    | 2     |
```